# Sending Meeting invite with mail attachment

Tags: .net, email-attachments, outlook-2010, meeting-request

I have created a MailMessage which is really a meeting request but problem is when it shows up in my Outlook I can
accept/decline like with any other meeting request. This is great. However,
now I am trying to add attachments to the MailMessage
 when I do this, it successfully adds the attachment however
when the email is received in Outlook it is no longer a meeting request I
can accept/decline, instead it's just an email with the meeting information
inside of it and the attachment attached. How do I programmatically attach
the attachment while at the same time keeping the meeting request
functionality?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
         if (file != null & fileName != string.Empty)
         {

             Attachment obj = new Attachment(fileName);
             msg.Attachments.Add(obj);            
         }

Comment: ystem.Net.Mime.ContentType calendarType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
calendarType.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
calendarType.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");
string bodyCalendar = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nMETHOD:REQUEST\r\nPRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nBEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\nTZID:(...";
AlternateView calendarView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyCalendar, calendarType);
calendarView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
msg.AlternateViews.Add(calendarView);

Comment: @user2323308 can you edit your question...?